# Excel Javascript API Detect Strikethrough Text & Sort

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm trying to use the Excel Javascript APi to sort text based on Strikethrough. What I would like to do is detect all strikethrough text in the range & set to say Red then sort.This is what I have but getting error..

ebugInfo: Object
code: "PropertyNotLoaded"
message: "The property 'strikethrough' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context."

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Add values to the range
    const range = sheet.getRange("A5:M500");

    let dataRange = sheet.getRange("A5:M500").load(["rowCount", "format", "values","font","strikethrough"]);

    console.log(dataRange.toJSON());
    await context.sync();

    for (var row = 0; row < dataRange.rowCount; row++) {
      dataRange.getRow(row).format.fill.clear();

      if (dataRange.getCell(row, 0).format.font.strikethrough == true) {
        dataRange.getRow(row).format.font.color = "Red";
      }
    }   
    
    // Sort the range
    const sortFields = [
      {
        key: 1,
        sortOn: Excel.SortOn.fontColor,
        ascending: false
      },
       {
        key: 0,
        ascending: true
      }
    ];
    range.sort.apply(sortFields);

    await context.sync();
  });
}
    
    /** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
    async function tryCatch(callback) {
      try {
        await callback();
      } catch (error) {
        // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: also tried conditional format as below but no joy 

    const conditionalFormat = range.conditionalFormats.add(
      Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom
    );

    // If a cell has a higher value than the one to its left, set that cell's font to green.
    conditionalFormat.custom.rule.formula = '=has_strikethrough(A5:M500)';
    conditionalFormat.custom.format.font.color = "red";

Comment: Please update your question to explain what is going wrong. You only explain what you want to do.

Comment: updated question  to better describe issue

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `load()` method correctly. Try replacing:

```
 let dataRange = sheet.getRange("A5:M500").load(["rowCount", "format", "values","font","strikethrough"]);
```

with

```
 let dataRange = sheet.getRange("A5:M500").load(["rowCount", "format/font/strikethrough", "values"]);
```

Also, see [load()](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model#load) for how to use the method.

Comment: Thanks Rick.. I already tried this but still get the same error.. "The property 'strikethrough' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context."

Comment: outputting value of dataRange to console using code console.log(JSON.stringify(dataRange, null, 4));     strikethrough is always null 
{
    "rowCount": 40,
    "format": {
        "font": {
            "strikethrough": null
        }
    }
}

Comment: ok it looks like the .load /format/font/strikethrough doesn't iterate through all the rows in the range when it is loaded..Unlike when you load values where you get all the values in the range.

Comment: ok cracked it!.. Property strikethrough is only available at the cell level not row so you have to test the specific cell & bingo..

Answer (score 0):

```
OfficeExtension.config.extendedErrorLogging = true;

$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    //let myUsedRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
    //myUsedRange.load(["rowCount", "format/font/strikethrough"]);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(myUsedRange.rowCount, null, 4));
    

    let dataRange = sheet.getRange("A5:M44").load(["rowCount", "rowIndex"]);
    await context.sync();

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(dataRange, null, 4));

    for (var row = 0; row < dataRange.rowCount; row++) {
      dataRange.getRow(row).format.fill.clear();

      let dataCell = dataRange.getCell(row, 1).load(["format/font/strikethrough"]);
      await context.sync();

      //console.log(JSON.stringify(dataCell, null, 4));

      if (dataCell.format.font.strikethrough != null) {
        if (dataCell.format.font.strikethrough == true) {
          dataRange.getRow(row).format.font.color = "Red";
        }
      }
    } 
    
    await context.sync();

    tryCatch(sort);

    await context.sync();

  });
}

async function sort() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Add values to the range
    let range = sheet.getRange("A5:M44");
    // Sort the range
    const sortFields = [
      {
        key: 1,
        sortOn: Excel.SortOn.fontColor,
        ascending: true
      },
      {
        key: 1,
        sortOn: Excel.SortOn.value,
        ascending: true
      }];
    range.sort.apply(sortFields);

    await context.sync();

  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}

    enter code here
```